# Android studio 3.6.1: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently updated gradle and android studio to 3.6.1 version. but, it always fails to build apk file and show the following error:

> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> > Multiple task action failures occurred:
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>       > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #11: Daemon startup failed
>         Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
>         This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> ```

How can I solve this issue?
Thank you for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1):

[Various bug reports](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=%22Windows%20Universal%20C%20Runtime%22) mention that installing Windows Universal C Runtime manually helps. See if that helps.

Download: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to install or Update Universal C Runtime in Windows Package on your machine:-
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c
2. Restart your Android studio.