# execution failed for appmergeDebugResources task in intelliJ android project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am not able to get over this error. I'm using IntelliJ 2020.1.1 and I've tried every suggested solution- upgrading(6.1) and downgrading(both 6.0 and 5.6.4) gradle, changing gradle properties, clean/rebuild etc. Nothing works.

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\MyApplication1

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-rc01-6040484-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 33s
11 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 7 up-to-date`

Comment: Check your layout file you are having syntax somewhere there

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836833/2000323

Comment: I had been trying to install CRT but it would always say "The update is not applicable to Computer". Today I found out that Service pack 1 was not installed on my system. Now CRT is installed and my project is finally running. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after installing Universal C Runtime. 
I was getting "The update is not applicable to your computer" message everytime I tried to install CRT. Turns out Service pack 1 was not installed on my system. CRT was installed after this update and my project also executed finally.