# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' while generateing APK

Tags: android

I can able to successfully build the project. While generation the signed APK using android studio. I am getting following error.

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

I am using android studio 4.1.0 with windows 10.

I checked all the answers in stack over flow . and i am unable to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you get `Execution failed for task ':...Resources'` error, you can try **Build>Clean Build** in Android Studio, if your problem is not solved, try **File>Invalidate Caches / Restart>Invalidate and Restart**, if your problem is still not solved it means you got an error in **Layout files** or **Drawable files** (or other xml files in /res folder), So you have to check all your **Xml files** in /res folder and solve problems.

**Edit**: you can try this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836833/13761413

Answer (score 0):

I closed Andriod Studio and deleted folder content from `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.gradle\caches` and tried again. That worked for me.