# building apk and loading devices not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have formatted my device and reinstall android studio, But there was a problem about building the apk and loading devices, this is the error log:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform material-1.0.0.aar (com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9790175d0d8e2a8d9c4671b25981480d\transformed\material-1.0.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform appcompat-1.2.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d4a2f07bb985ca8a3b4fdda3dc8c1d67\transformed\appcompat-1.2.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform appcompat-1.2.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d4a2f07bb985ca8a3b4fdda3dc8c1d67\transformed\appcompat-1.2.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.3.1.aar (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Kattah.gradle\caches\transforms-3\785713687875c127bedc5751b63fc5e2\transformed\core-1.3.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
22 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 21 up-to-date

Android studio version: 4.2.1. this is a screen shot to show my android studio interface, cannot load any device.
[image: screen shot to show my android studio]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio 3.6.1: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835127/android-studio-3-6-1-a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradl)

Comment: my operating system is windows 8.1 64 bit. I tried to install Universal C Runtime from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49081 but there was a massage : (this update is not applicable to your computer)