# When I modify any layout it gives me an error related to Windows Universal C Runtime on Windows 10

Tags: windows, android-studio, windows-10

Android Studio was working fine but I modified a layout and now it gives me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
 > AAPT2 aapt2-7.1.3-7984345-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
 Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
 This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Everything worked normally but at the moment this error started. If I restart AS I can compile but if I modify any layout it happens again. I have read that the solution is to install Windows Universal C Runtime but I can't find it for Windows 10. If the solution you propose is to install Windows Universal C Runtime please provide the official download link for Windows 10.

Comment: Might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60835127/180538

Comment: almost the same error but i coultd fint any solution yet, so i move to linux